# Как решить эту задачку?

Tags: c++, математика, теория-вероятностей, моделирование

Компьютер бросает кубик (с помощью генератора случайных чисел). Посчитать через сколько попыток выпадет шестерка.

Comment: как вы собираетесь это посчитать, если используется рандом? уточните вопрос

Comment: Честно говоря,я сам в шоке.Задали нам сделать эту задачку)

Comment: это полный текст задачи?

Comment: Да,это полный текст задачи.

Comment: в таком случае уточняйте у преподавателя что он там курит - в таком виде она не решаема

Comment: элементарно. генерируете числа от 1 до 6. как получилось 6 , пишите сколько раз было сгенерировано число (брошен кубик)

Comment: Хорошо,я вас понял.

Comment: В среднем шестерка будет выпадать через шесть бросков.

Answer (score 5):

```
int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    for(int tries = 0, len = 0;;)
    {
        int n = 1;
        while(rand()%6 != 5) n++;
        len += n;
        tries++;
        cout << setw(10) << double(len)/tries << "\r";
    }
}
```

и любуйтесь усредняемым значением :)